# React Native hide Topbar

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am new to react native and I am trying to remove the topbar (the gray part):

[image]

My code:

```
function Login() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.background}>
      <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>hey</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: { backgroundColor: colours.primaryColour, height: "100%" },
});
```

From my java experience I know to change in styles.xml to change the themes to noActionBar but it is already there but I still have a naviagtion bar. If you know how please let me know.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your code. thanks

Comment: Is this a screen in navigation ?

Answer (score 0):

You Should Add `headerVisible:false` in `Start.js` file

example code:

```
const Start = createStackNavigator({
  Splash: { screen: Splash },
  Home: { screen: screens },
  Login: { screen: Login },
  Resend: { screen: Resend },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Splash',
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerVisible: false,
  }
}
```

Comment: did not work :/